# Akka BalancingPool using a PinnedDispatcher

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka

I have a few database IO operations I would like to run concurrently.  In my case it would be best to use a BalancingPool Router.

The docs say if blocking operations are to occur in the workers then one should use a thread-pool-executor rather than the default fork-join-dispatcher.

I did not want to configure it in the Akka conf file so I think this would be the way to do it in code:

```
  val router = context.actorOf(BalancingPool(5).withDispatcher("my-pinned-dispatcher").props(Props[History]), "HistoryBalancingRouter")
```

But the docs say for a PinnedDispatcher:

> This dispatcher dedicates a unique thread for each actor using it;
> i.e. each actor will have its own thread pool with only one thread in
> the pool.
>
> Mailboxes: Any, creates one per Actor

Whereas for the BalancingPool it says workers share a single mailbox:

> The **BalancingPool** automatically uses a special BalancingDispatcher for
> its routees - disregarding any dispatcher that is set on the the
> routee Props object. This is needed in order to implement the
> balancing semantics via sharing the same mailbox by all the routees.
>
> While it is not possible to change the dispatcher used by the routees,
> it is possible to fine tune the used executor. **By default the
> fork-join-dispatcher is used** and can be configured as explained in
> Dispatchers. **In situations where the routees are expected to perform
> blocking operations it may be useful to replace it with a
> thread-pool-executor hinting the number of allocated threads
> explicitly**

So what is actually happening with mailboxes and threads here?

Is my example a sane way to implement a BalancingPool using a thread-pool-executor?

Answer (score 1):

The BalancingPool always works with a BalancingDispatcher, it will simply refuse your PinnedDispatcher setting. The reason is exactly that the BalancingDispatcher allows actors to share a common mailbox (for performance) which other Dispatchers do not support.

Please note that several of the Dispatchers allow you to configure the *Executor* that they will use inside. By default, for BalancingPool it is the `fork-join-executor` (the docs incorrectly say "fork-join-dispatcher") but you can change it to use a `thread-pool-executor`. An example dispatcher configuration is here: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.13/scala/dispatchers.html#Setting_the_dispatcher_for_an_Actor you just need to change the executor type